# is there a drupal module that enables a live chat in a drupal site?

Tags: drupal, chat

is there a drupal module that enables a live chat in a drupal site?

Answer (score 4):

I recommend [drupalchat](http://drupal.org/project/drupalchat), it is the most maintained and complete version. It uses [node.js](http://drupal.org/project/nodejs) as the server. It works on Drupal 6 and 7 and has many features.

Answer (score 3):

Drupal.org has an excellent search, a simple search revealed [these candidates](http://drupal.org/search/apachesolr_search/live%20chat?filters=type%3Aproject_project).

Answer (score 2):

I use [ClickDesk](http://www.clickdesk.com/) on my Wordpress site as a plugin, It's just copy pasting the code; I guess it should work with Drupal as well.

Answer (score 1):

http://drupal.org/project/bowob
Have a look at bowob chat it gives you an interface which would be useful for implementing chat in a social networking environment. If you exam the api you can see what other modules bowob will go with well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Drupal Olark module

http://drupal.org/project/olark

I believe it can handle visitors when you are offline too.

Answer (score 1):

You should try LetsSyncro [Live Chat & Image interaction Module for Drupal](http://letssyncro.com/AddOns/Drupal). This module adds image interaction to the traditional Live chat functionality.

You can find the installation guide in the following link: http://letssyncro.com/AddOns/Drupal

Answer (score 0):

```
http://drupal.org/project/zopim
```

Zopim will provide you with the admin panel to administer you online and offline chat, but on their site only. Helped me a lot. Hope this will help you too.

Answer (score 0):

Check [chatroom](http://drupal.org/project/chatroom) module. It doesn't depend on any third party services and it offers a lot flexibility. You can make both - a site support chat and a community open chat room with it.

Version for D7 requires node.js I think.

Most of others depend on third party services which require registration and membership.

Answer (score 0):

At our website we used Mibbit to embed chat events. It is based on the old IRC system so it has zero learning curve for that audience. It worked really well and the cost was minimal, might be zero for most regular users.

http://www.mibbit.com/

Their staff was also extremely helpful and just generally cool to work with. They are always on their own support chat channel and so you get instant answers. We eventually stopped doing corespondent interviews so the system is not used now, but I would use them again without hesitation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i'm actually using [a facebook like chat](http://drupal.org/project/drupalchat) that's easy to configure with YUI

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually using [drupalchat](http://drupal.org/project/drupalchat/): a facebook like chat and easy to configure with yui